# How sort a System.Collections.Generic.List in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting

I using a genric list(m_equipmentList ) which is collection of objects (Schedule_Payitem).
How can sort list according to a proerty of child object  ?

```
Dim m_equipmentList As New List(Of Schedule_Payitem)
```

Need to sort m_equipmentList on basis of resourceid property of Schedule_Payitem.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I was able to use the lambda expression from Jon Skeet in one of my projects.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Are you using VB9? If so, I'd use a [lambda expression](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/02/lambda-expressions-in-vb9.html) to create a `Comparer(Of Schedule_PayItem)`. Otherwise, write a short class to implement `IComparer(Of Schedule_PayItem)`. pass whichever one you've got into List.Sort.

An example for the lambda expression (untested):

```
m_equipmentList.Sort(Function(p1, p2) p1.ResourceID.CompareTo(p2.ResourceID))
```

And for the `IComparer(Of Schedule_PayItem)`:

```
Public Class PayItemResourceComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Schedule_PayItem)
    Public Function Compare(ByVal p1 As Schedule_PayItem, _
                            ByVal p2 As Schedule_PayItem) As Integer
        Return p1.ResourceID.CompareTo(p2.ResourceID)
    End Function
End Class

...

m_equipmentList.Sort(New PayItemResourceComparer)
```

Comment: Helpful tip to specify Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Schedule_PayItem).  I was getting an error: 'System.Collections.IComparer' has no type parameters.  A little searching helped me find that two such interfaces with same name exist, one in System.Collections and another in System.Collections.Generic.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know vb.net so I did it in C#

```
m_equipmentList.Sort(
   (payItem1,payItem2)=>payItem1.ResourceID.CompareTo(payItem2.ResourceID));
```

and using the reflector translated it to vb.net hope it helps

```
m_equipmentList.Sort(
Function (ByVal payItem1 As Schedule_Payitem, ByVal payItem2 As Schedule_Payitem) 
    Return payItem1.ResourceID.CompareTo(payItem2.ResourceID)
End Function)
```

or you can inherit Schedule_Payitem from  IComparable and implement CompareTo and then just call `m_equipmentList.Sort()`

Comment: This is a great way for lots of problems :D

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish sorting the list in descending order by changing this-

```
m_equipmentList.Sort(
Function (ByVal payItem1 As Schedule_Payitem, ByVal payItem2 As Schedule_Payitem) 
    Return payItem1.ResourceID.CompareTo(payItem2.ResourceID)
End Function)
```

to this

```
m_equipmentList.Sort(
Function (ByVal payItem1 As Schedule_Payitem, ByVal payItem2 As Schedule_Payitem) 
    Return payItem2.ResourceID.CompareTo(payItem1.ResourceID)
End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim m_equipmentList As New List(Of Schedule_Payitem)


m_equipmentList.Sort(delegate(Schedule_Payitem p1, Schedule_Payitem p2)
              {
                  return p1.resourceid .CompareTo(p2.resourceid );
              });
```

Comment: VB.Net doesn't have anonymous delegate support until vs2008, so the conversion from this code may not be trivial.

Comment: You code is a mix of C# and VB.Net ! ';' character at end of line is for C# !