# Need help re-arranging elements in my List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, list

this is my situation:

I got a list of objects. Each object has a property called Z (integer).
There will come a point during run-time I will want to re-arrange such objects in my list depending on their Z property. The objects with lower Z go first in the list, and the ones with higher will go last.

I have thought of a couple things, like making a new List, then loop through each object in the original list as many times as the amount of objects such list has (so if it has 10 objects, I would loop 100 times), and each iteration will check the Z values. When a cycle is done (for every 10 iterations), I will remove the object with the lowest Z number in cycle and add it to the new List. And so on until the 100 iterations are done.

That makes sense, but might be quite inefficient specially since I might have a bunch (BUNCH) of objects... Any better ideas?

Comment: That would sort it but not in an efficient manner.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438715/how-sort-a-system-collections-generic-list-in-vb-net) discusses sorting lists in vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to get the objects is the correct order

```
Dim list As List(Of MyType) = ...
list.Sort(Function (x, y) x.Z.CompareTo(y.Z))
```

**EDIT** More complex comparison function as requested in comments

```
Public Function MyTypeCompare(ByVal left as MyType, ByVal right as MyType) As Integer
  Dim result = left.Z.CompareTo(right.Z)
  if result = 0 Then
    Return Result
  Else
    Return left.Created.CompareTo(right.Created)
  End If
End Function

list.Sort(AddressOf MyTypeCompare)
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than my scenario.

Comment: Could you also use LINQ to Objects?

Comment: I run this code many times and I think there is something... wrong. Could you explain me what that line of code does?

Comment: Ah I think I know the problem: some objects have the same Z value. If that is the case, I want to give priority to the one that was created first (put it first). Any ideas?

Comment: @Omega for that you'll need a more complex sorting function.  Essentially if Z values are equal then compare the next value on the list.

Comment: @Omega added a more complex sort in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that your Object class implements IComparer interface and that you create the proper predicate methods for things.

Not to be too self promoting, but I wrote a blog entry outlining this setup [here](http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/how-to-sortfind-custom-objects-in-a-list-with-vb-net/).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a sorting algorithm (one of the first things you learn in basic Computer Science.)  There are many algorithms in existence, so depending on how much you want to learn, check out the wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Depending on the size of your data you can pick a more efficient (and complex) sorting method to implement.  I'm not sure exactly what your situation is and why you are doing this, but bubble-sort is easy to understand and implement, so if the numbers on the above link are overwhelming to you, focus on this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Thanks to wiki, here's an easy to understand .gif of what its actually doing in the above link.

I hope this helps. (I apologize if its too basic of an answer, I am new around these parts.)

Comment: I don't think they need to worry about a sorting algorithm, the List<T> object already has the basics for that, you just need to give it a method of comparing items within it and the object handles the rest.