# How to sort (order by) list of objects according to specific column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting, gridview

How to sort List of objects according to specific field (`sort expression`) and the direction (`sort direction`)..

For example :

```
TransactionList.ToList<UserTransactionDTO>()
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your list is a list of a custom type and you want to sort by one or multiple properties:

```
var trans = transactions.OrderBy(t => t.PropertyName)
                        .ThenBy(t => t.DifferentPropertyName)
```

If you want to order descending instead:

```
var trans = transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.PropertyName)
                        .ThenByDescending(t => t.DifferentPropertyName)
```

[`Enumerable.OrderBy` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)

Comment: is there some way to make `PropertyName` as a variable , so that i can pass it through a method?

Comment: @just_name: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var people = new List<Person>(); //Fill it
var sorted = people.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Age);
```

And otherwise use OrderByDescending();

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `IComparer<T>`, if you want to use complex sorting.

See: [How sort a System.Collections.Generic.List in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438715/how-sort-a-system-collections-generic-list-in-vb-net)